# lightbox 2 no directional arrows

Tags: lightbox2

Not too sure if it's something that I'm missing but I'm using Lokesh Dhakar's lightbox 2 (Thanks Lokesh!) but I'm not seeing the arrows? when I click to the left/right or us the cursor it works just fine but no visible signs for the user.

Comment: Ignore me, found my error.... Really silly!

Comment: So, maybe not that silly after all (Well I hope not!) I have downloaded the icons now how do I get them to show on the images? Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you provide more details about your issue. It is very likely that the images are not in the correct location.